# How is the "combine each with each" operation called?

Tags: php, arrays, matrix, operators

I have a matrix represented in PHP as an array:

```
array(
    array('a','b'),   //   a | b
    array('c','d')    //   c | d
)
```

and I have a second matrix represented in a similar way (here without inner arrays, but I don't mind adding them):

```
array(
    'e',              //   e
    'f'               //   f
)
```

I'd like to have a combination like this:

```
array(
    array('a','b','e'),   //   a | b | e
    array('c','d','e')    //   c | d | e
    array('a','b','f'),   //   a | b | f
    array('c','d','f')    //   c | d | f
)
```

I was trying to find a code snippet that does that for me, but I failed because I don't even know if this kind of operation has a name. Has it?

(I don't want anyone to write that code snippet, I can do that myself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the cartesian product. There is no native PHP function to calculate that.

Comment: I know this term from SQL/set theory and found some implementations but none of them worked if the elements on the left are already ordered pairs. Accepted anyway.

Comment: If you would like an implementation I would be happy to suggest one. You stated in the question that you didn't want one, however.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else **does** want an implementation, the following would create a cartesian product of two arrays:

```
$cartesian_product_values = array();
$cartesian_product_arrays = array();
foreach($array1 as $a1) {
    foreach($array2 as $a2) {
        //Concatenate values in arrays
        $cartesian_product_values[] = $a1.$a2;
        $cartesian_product_values[] = $a2.$a1;
        //Or merge arrays
        $cartesian_product_arrays[] = array_merge($a1, $a2);
    }
}
```

And additionally, if you want the values from $array1 and $array2 in the final array, you can merge the two arrays together before the nested foreach loops:

```
$cartesian_product = array_merge($array1, $array2);
foreach($array1 as $a1) {
    foreach($array2 as $a2) {
        array_push($cartesian_product, $a1.$a2);
        array_push($cartesian_product, $a2.$a1);
    }
}
```